# I'm next to certain that

Tags: expressions

I'm a little confused. What the expression "I'm next to certain that" try to say and emphasize in the sentence below?

> I'm next to certain that if you continue to complain, you will lose your job.

Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI there are a number of 'next to' constructions, such as 'next to nothing' ('there was next to nothing left')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phrase means "I am close to certain" or "I am almost positive" or "I am 99% sure".

If *certainty* was a point in space, then "next to certain" would be a point very nearby.  Being *next to certain* means you are very confident about something, although you are leaving a small chance that you might be incorrect.